# Why does 'for_each' not reading function object

Tags: c++

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
class Sum {
public:
    Sum(T i = 0) : res(i) {}
    void operator()(T x) { res =res + x; }
    T result() const { return res; }
private:
    T res;
};

int main() {
    Sum<int> s;
    vector<int> vec;
    vec.insert(vec.begin(), 10);
    vec.insert(vec.begin()+1, 10);
    vec.insert(vec.begin()+2, 10);

    vector<int>::iterator itr = vec.begin();
    cout << *itr << endl;
    for_each(vec.begin(), vec.end(), s);
    cout << "sum is" << s.result() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This is my code. I want to add `vec` values in class Sum `res`. `for_each` should be calling `s`'s `operator()`, so the result should be 30, but it shows 0.

I think adding value in vector has no problem. Why is the `s.operator()` is not working?

Comment: Also Read: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2048967/1870232

Answer (score 4):

[`for_each`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each) takes its third argument by value which means every invocation of `operator()` affects a completely separate copy of `s`. There's an algorithm for exactly what you're doing called [`std::accumulate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate), but if you want this to work with `for_each` you need to pass `s` "by reference" by using `std::ref` from `<functional>`.

```
for_each(vec.begin(), vec.end(), ref(s));
```

Answer (score 3):

`for_each` returns a copy of the passed-in functor that provides the "result" of the iteration (whatever the result is). Change your call to:

`auto s = for_each(vec.begin(), vec.end(), Sum<int>());`